# how to prefill data with angucomplete plugin?

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular with angucomplete plugin. https://github.com/darylrowland/angucomplete

How do I prefill the value of the autcomplete textfield? I can't find the answer on the documentation. Is anyone have encounter the same problem and able to solve it?

example:
I am creating the form to add/edit product. product depends on the part. so the part is using angucomplete.

when "editing product" the angucomplete need to prefilled with the part from variable or data binding.

my code :

```
<div style="display:inline-block;" ng-repeat="part in Productparts">
        <!--<input type="text" />-->
        <div angucomplete id="autocompletefield{{part.counter}}" placeholder="part" pause="100" selectedObject="partSelectedObject" url="http//www.blablabla.com/part?keyword=" datafield="part" titlefield="name" minlength="2" inputclass="form-control form-control-small"></div>
    </div>
```

now when I am editing the product, the angucomplete needs to prefilled with object part.name

Comment: Not getting your question could you please elaborate more?

Comment: the input textbox is empty unless we type it. can we prefill the input textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is that I have to update the plugin so it accept prefilled value.

in angucompletejs file in scope I add :

```
"initialValue": "@initialvalue"
```

and in link I add :

```
if($scope.initialValue){
            $scope.searchStr = $scope.initialValue;
        }
```

now I can use the initialValue attribute.

```
<div style="display:inline-block;" ng-repeat="part in Productparts">
<div angucomplete id="autocompletefield{{part.counter}}" placeholder="part" pause="100" selectedObject="partSelectedObject" url="http//www.blablabla.com/part?keyword=" datafield="part" titlefield="name" minlength="2" inputclass="form-control form-control-small" initialValue="{{part.name}}"></div>
</div>
```